# Caption not appearing in flextable table when saved as image

Tags: r, image, fonts, flextable

I want to save a flextable object as an image.  I can see the table with the caption in the viewer. But then, when I save this as an image, the caption no longer appears.  This has only changed today, previously not a problem. I was trying to change the font of the table and caption and had updated my flextable package version. Using most recent version `flextable_0.9.1`.

The other problem I'm having, is how to change the font of the caption as well as the table

```
> gdtools::installed_gfonts()
[1] "Poppins"   "Noto Sans"
```

This is what I am doing:

```
i1= flextable(head(iris))%>%
  set_caption( "My table")

save_as_image(i1, "Outputs/i1.png")
```

This is the image file saved:

[image]

```
#And trying to change font of caption:

i2= flextable(head(iris))%>%
  set_caption(as_paragraph( "My table"))

font(i2, fontname = "Noto Sans", part = "all")

or 
i3= flextable(head(iris))%>%
  set_caption(as_paragraph(as_chunk( "My table")))
font(i3, fontname = "Noto Sans", part = "all")
```

[image]

The caption font isn't changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version you see in the viewer was created implicitly by:

```
> flextable:::print.flextable
function (x, preview = "html", align = "center", ...) 
{
    # various if/else options (omitted for brevity)
    else if (preview == "html") {
        print(browsable(htmltools_value(x = x, ft.align = align)))
    }
    # various other if/else options (also omitted for brevity)
    invisible(NULL)
}
```

While the version you get from `save_as_image`, as of 0.9.1, is:

```
> save_as_image
function (x, path, expand = 10, res = 200, ...) 
{
    # checks on object's class (omitted for brevity)

    gr <- gen_grob(x, fit = "fixed", just = "center")

    # saving generated grob (also omitted for brevity)
}
```

The former, which calls on `htmltools_value()` internally, includes code for handling a flextable's caption. The latter's equivalent (`gen_grob`) does not. That is why the results differ between what you see in the viewer & the saved image.

As for why this change only showed up recently for you, my guess is that your original flextable version was from some time back, when the an earlier version of the `save_as_image` function **worked by taking a screenshot of HTML output** of the flextable, with support from webshot / webshot2 packages (here's a [link](https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/blob/90724091d235bfd236b0efdba83583236c491ffd/R/printers.R) to a snapshot of the code repo from Jan 2023, which described this function as such).

The package creator mentioned this in a recent [issue](https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/522) on his GH repo:

> yes, there have been lot of complaints about `webshot` and `webshot2`, so
> we decided to stop using it.
>
> Now `save_as_image()` only use `ragg` and produce png and we are happy
> with this version.

I guess ultimately, different output options have different conventions when it comes to table captions, & it may not seem natural to everyone to expect the exact same appearance in a Word document, a PowerPoint deck, a PDF file, a HTML page, etc. So a case may be made for `save_as_image` to look intentionally different from the html output version. I'm not in a position to say.

On the second part of your question, if you want to change the caption's appearance (in html output), you can specify it within `as_chunk`, e.g.:

```
flextable(head(iris))%>%
  set_caption(as_paragraph(as_chunk( "My table", 
                                     props = fp_text_default(color = "red", 
                                                             font.family = "Times New Roman"))))
```